# echarts sunburst virtual root node behavior

Tags: echarts

When using nodeClick = rootToNode the central area changes size when clicking on outer sections of the sunburst. Is it possible to have the central area not change size?

If someone could explain why the radius of the central area changes that would be much appreciated.

In this demo https://jsfiddle.net/jku8ct3g/2/ click on the donut "f" and see the central white area is replaced by a larger red area. What does the central area represent?

```
//Code is long to post here
```

Comment: What do you mean by central area? Please provide your option, and check if radius is in number for the first element in levels.

Comment: Hi @Ovilia I've added an example to clarify.